# What is the complement of the null space??

Tags: linear-algebra

Given an $A: R^n \rightarrow R^m$ that maps from $x$ to $b$, the null space is the set of $x$s that map to $b=0$.

What is the set of $x$s that map to $b\neq0$? Is it $R^n - {nullspace}$. Or doesn't that form a space? And if so, what is the correct answer?

Comment: It isn't indeed a subspace. The correct answer depends very much on $A$, there's no general answer, as far as I know.

Comment: @Bernard: thanks. Is the row space somehow related? I read it's perpendicular to the nullspace, but does that imply something?

Comment: The row space is the column space of the matrix of the dual linear mapping. Maybe that's what they mean in what you've read.

Answer (score 1):

The row space is the orthogonal complement of the null space, $(\operatorname{row}A)^\perp=\operatorname{ker}A$, which follows pretty easily from the definition.   This is because you dot the rows of $A$ with $x$ to get $b$.  So if $b=0$, all the dot products are zero.

The solution set of $Ax=b\,,b\not=0$, on the other hand,  if nonempty,  is the set $\{x_0+y\mid y\in\operatorname{ker}A\}$, where $x_0$ is any particular solution.